# alternative to hamcrest containsInAnyOrder first win strategy

Tags: hamcrest

Consider the following test:

```
@Test
public void containsInAnyOrderImplementsFirstWinStrategy() {
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);
    assertThat(list, IsIterableContainingInAnyOrder.containsInAnyOrder(
       Matchers.greaterThan(3), Matchers.lessThan(5), equalTo(1), equalTo(2)));
}
```

I would expect the test to be green but it fails with:

> java.lang.AssertionError: 
>   Expected: iterable with items [a value greater than <3>, a value less than <5>, <1>, <2>] in any order
>        but: not matched: <3>

The reason, as far as I can see, is that hamcrest takes a first win strategy and since lessThan(5) matches 1, this matcher is no longer available to match `3`.

Is there an alternative method which implements a more complete `containsInAnyOrder` (at the cost of a bigger O)